# How do I find the highest level TR that contains a specific ID nested in a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some HTML that looks like this (NOTE: I know this code isn't great but I didn't design it originally and some of it is auto generated):

```
<table id="tab1">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td><span>Some text</span></td>
        <td><span>more text</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="inp1" onclick="DoSomething(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td><span>Some text</span></td>
        <td><span>more text</span></td>
        <td><table id="tab2"><tbody>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" id="inp2" onclick="DoSomething(this);" /><span>item</span></td></tr>
        </tbody></table></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All of that is embedded in a table which is also embedded in a table and so on. In the `DoSomething(this)` function I want to retrieve the TR underneath the table `tab1`. I'm having trouble figuring out the jquery necessary for this. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
function DoSomething(control) {
    var parentTab = '<%=tab1.ClientID %>';
    var tr = $('#' + parentTab + ' > tbody > tr').has('#' + $(control).attr('id')).get(0);
}
```

This seems really messy but works. Is there a cleaner way to do this? If it helps the input inside the table will always be a radio button and a radio button will never appear outside of a sub table. Ideally I'd like to do this without having to know the id of `tab1` but that seems impossible.

Comment: Umm, well there is no `tbody` element in the HTML. Also, none of the `tr` elements you show have an id, which is also going to cause problems. Is this the actual HTML, or did you forget to copy over some of the attributes and tags?

Comment: I added the missing tbody tags and missing ids on the the rows. There are no IDs on the rows contained in tab2.

Answer (score 3):

`.has()` also accepts DOM elements as an argument, so you can simplify to:

```
var tr = $('#' + parentTab + ' > tbody > tr').has(control)[0];
```